# Maven process-classes, only process the ones changed by compiler:compile

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have written a maven mojo that does in-place JavaFlow instrumentation of a set of java classes specified by a fileset. That is, srcfile = destfile.

The plugin triggers on process-classes phase.

If I do a mvn clean install this works out fine.
However, if I after a mvn clean install do an mvn install it runs the processing again, even though none of the class files have changed. In my case this is very very bad... :(

Since I do the instrumentation in place I can't really use file timestamps either.

I need some way to tell my mojo to only run on files that were recompiled by compiler:compile... any ideas?

Comment: What about checksums for the files located into target/your-maven-plugin/.... ?

Comment: Yeah... thats my backup plan... :(

Right now I'm looking at StaleSourceScanner, the one that compiler plugin uses to detect stale resources.

But no matter what I do I can't get it to detect anything as stale :(

Comment: Have you taken a look into the maven-compiler-plugin how it is solved there...may be you can take the code?

Comment: Yes, they use a StaleSourceScanner, but it appears to update its internal data after the compile, so for my plugin its never stale :/

Comment: I ended up doing the checksum thing... hopefuly it wont blow up in my face later.
If you want answer credits, post it as an answer :)

Comment: Thanks but this isn't really an answer from my side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried using StaleSourceScanner, but it didn't work as I wanted.

So I ended up doing checksums on the file after instrumentation and checking them during the next build step.

As an added safety measure I modified the JavaFlow source so that if a class is instrumented twice an exception will be thrown.

EDIT: Actually, now I use ASM to check if the class has been instrumented or not... and if it has, don't instrument it. No checksums anymore.

Comment: Marc, how do you check that file has been instrumented via ASM?

Comment: Oh, that was awhile ago... I went through multiple solutions.

I think the last one added an interface to the list of implemented interfaces after instrumenting each. (This interface was empty, so it didn't do anything). After that I simply checked for the existence of the interface.